# Difference between useEffect and useLayoutEffect in react 18

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React docs state that

> starting in react 18, the function passed to useEffect will fire
> synchronously before layout and paint when it's the result of a
> discrete user input such as a click.

However, it also states that

> this only affects the timing of when the function passed to useEffect
> is called and that updates scheduled inside these effects are still
> deferred.
> This is different than useLayoutEffect, which fires the function and
> processes the updates inside of it immediately.

What is meant by the second statement here? What is the docs referring to by the word "updates", and how can this be tested practically to distinguish between useLayoutEffect?

Comment: This seems pretty promising to me: https://dev.to/nibble/what-is-uselayouteffect-hook-and-when-do-you-use-it-3lan

Comment: @caTS I did just read the article and as I expected it the article was written before react 18. And I did read it thoroughly but it doesn't really answer the question. I understand the differences between them before react 18; however, after react 18, they've made changes. And what I don't understand is the word 'updates' and how I can test it to see the differences as they are now.

Comment: This discussion https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/128 on github might be useful